# Foundation 4 - Tabs to responsive dropdown

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I was wondering if there is an option that foundation 4 tabs goes to dropdown when window become small.

```
<div class="section-container auto" data-section>
  <section class="active">
    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel1">Section 1</a></p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
      <p>Content of section 1.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel2">Section 2</a></p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
      <p>Content of section 2.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Here, links are just  inside

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In foundation you can use visibility classes to control the elements based on screen sizes.
   using visibility classes show-for-small-only and hide-for-small-only we present the div
respectively

```
<div class="show-for-small-only">
    <a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1" class="button dropdown">Dropdown Button</a><br>
    <ul id="drop1" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

<div class="hide-for-small-only">
<dl class="tabs" data-tab>
  <dd class="active"><a href="#panel2-1">Tab 1</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#panel2-2">Tab 2</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#panel2-3">Tab 3</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#panel2-4">Tab 4</a></dd>
</dl>
<div class="tabs-content">
  <div class="content active" id="panel2-1">
    <p>First panel content goes here...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel2-2">
    <p>Second panel content goes here...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel2-3">
    <p>Third panel content goes here...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel2-4">
    <p>Fourth panel content goes here...</p>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Ok, but can i make thins links in dropdown menu to change content ? Beacuse its not working

Comment: No in order for the links in dropdown to change content you have add JavaScript.

Comment: I don't think this works in Foundation 4. It would work on Foundation 5.